# Posting Form via Jquery not passing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using the following code to post a form but am not getting the form data passed to the code behind?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#Submit").live("click", function () {
                var formData = $("#CreateOrder").serialize();
                $.post("/Orders/SaveExtra", formData, function (result) {                    
                    if (result.created) {
                        alert("Saved successfully!");
                    } else {
                        alert("Error!");
                    }
                });                
            });
        });
    </script>

    <input id='Submit' type='submit' value='Save Extra' style="height: 30px; width: 130px; margin-top:8px;margin-right: 15px; float:right " />   

<form id="CreateOrder" method="post" action="/Orders/Create" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" >     


...

</form>
```

I have the main form which calls a different method to the save one, so I need two submits but it doesn't seem to be posting the data from the form?

Comment: try to inspect the formData value before the ajax call - and why your submit button is outside your form?

Comment: hi, I have one submit input within the form and another button outisde becuase they both call different methods inside the same controller.

Comment: @okenshield you can keep both submit buttons in same form. Infact keeping both submit buttons inside form is the correct approach. Also, once you will put this submit button inside your form ( ID of both submit buttons should be same ) this may resolve your problem. Alternatively try to print forma data using  `console.debug ( formData )`   . This will tell you what actually you are trying to post. Hopefully it is null there.

Answer (score 0):

In the post's first parameter, you need to specify **the full path** of your service. Example:

```
$.post("http://localhost:8080/Orders/SaveExtra", formData, function(result){...}
```

On a side note, if your jquery version is higher than 1.7 it is recommended that you change your .live() with .on(), since .live() is deprecated.

Comment: hi, it is calling the method ok in the controller but the data seems to be null, that's why I thought it might need the live()?

Comment: this does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If the data you are receiving is `JSON`, I would add that to the POST call as the `datatype` value.

```
   $.post("/Orders/SaveExtra", formData, function (result) {                    
           if (result.created) {
                alert("Saved successfully!");
            } else {
                   alert("Error!");
            }
   },"json");
```

And If you are using jQuery 1.7+, i suggest you to switch to [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `live`. So your code will look like

```
 $(function(){
      $(document).on("click","#Submit",function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var formData = $("#CreateOrder").serialize();
          $.post("/Orders/SaveExtra", formData, function (result) {                    
              if (result.created) {
                   alert("Saved successfully!");
               } else {
                   alert("Error!");
               }
         },"json");   
       });
 });
```

Comment: @okenshield: Do you see any scrip errors in firebug console ?

Comment: @okenshield: Actually i missed the serialize statement in my example. That might have thrown  a script error. Updated my answer now.